# How to maintain same hashcode even though ordering of object change in List in Java?

Tags: java, hashcode

```
Class A {
   private String test1;
   private String test2;
}

Class Feature {
   private List<A> obj;

   /* 
    HashCode which should return same value even though i change ordering of objects in List
   */
}
```

Current behaviour:

```
> List<A> contains [obj1, obj2, obj3] -> Some hashCode (Ex: 9058203945)
> List<A> contains [obj2, obj1, obj3] -> Some other hashCode (Ex:-23423423)
```

> What i want is my hashCode of List should be same if i change the ordering of elements in List.

Any help?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you talking about the result of the [`hashCode` method on `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#hashCode())?

Comment: Write your hash code method in a way such that the order of elements does not matter. For example, take the XOR of the hash codes of the elements. Another way would be to use a `Set` instead of a `List`.

Comment: Feature class hashcode is depended on `List<A>` hashCode which basically means you'd like to change the behavior of (for example) ArrayList hashCode function which is impossible. You'd have to override your class hashCode function.
Also, orders usually matter in hash. It's really a bad practice to not to care about orders in hash function.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Not sure, but I guess you are referring to the [`List#hashCode`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/List.html#hashCode()) method.

## Ordering of elements is the very definition of `List`

The order of the elements contained in a `List` is the core concept of a list. So changing the order results in another list altogether. Those two lists are not conceptually equal, so they do not, and should not, return the same hash value (except by freak coincidence, which is exceedingly rare if using decent [hash function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_function)).

Technically you could subclass a `List` class and override the `hashCode` method. You could do whatever you like in your own `hashCode` method. But this would be a *very* bad idea as it violates the semantics of a `List`.

## `Set`

If you do not care about the order of your elements, use another collection instead of `List`.

`Set` is likely what you need. A `Set` holds a bunch of objects, not necessarily in any particular order. Some implementations iterate in a certain order, some do not promise any order.

```java
Set < DayOfWeek > setX = Set.of( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY , DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY );
Set < DayOfWeek > setY = Set.of( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY , DayOfWeek.TUESDAY );

boolean sameHashCode = ( setX.hashCode() == setY.hashCode() );

System.out.println( "setX.hashCode() = " + setX.hashCode() );
System.out.println( "setY.hashCode() = " + setY.hashCode() );
System.out.println( "sameHashCode = " + sameHashCode );
```

When run.

> setX.hashCode() = -838114520
>
> setY.hashCode() = -838114520
>
> sameHashCode = true

This works across different implementations of `Set`.

```java
Set < DayOfWeek > setX =new TreeSet<>() ;
setX.add( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY);
setX.add( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY);

Set < DayOfWeek > setY = new HashSet <>();
setY.add( DayOfWeek.WEDNESDAY );
setY.add( DayOfWeek.TUESDAY );

boolean sameHashCode = ( setX.hashCode() == setY.hashCode() );
```

> sameHashCode = true

Those were enum objects above. Does it work with `String` objects? Yes.

```
Set < String > setX = new TreeSet <>();
setX.add( "Alice" );
setX.add( "Bob" );
setX.add( "Carol" );

Set < String > setY = new HashSet <>();
setY.add( "Bob" );
setY.add( "Alice" );
setY.add( "Carol" );

boolean sameHashCode = ( setX.hashCode() == setY.hashCode() );
```

> sameHashCode = true

## `Set` is distinct

Be aware of one major difference between `Set` and `List`:

- `List` allows duplicates. One object can be added to the list multiple times, and take multiple slots in that list.
- `Set` forbids duplicates. A `Set` is distinct, holding only a single reference to any particular object. Adding one particular object multiple times has no effect after the first time.

To quote the [`Set`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Set.html) Javadoc:

> A collection that contains no duplicate elements. More formally, sets contain no pair of elements e1 and e2 such that e1.equals(e2), and at most one null element. As implied by its name, this interface models the mathematical set abstraction.

```java
Set < String > setY = new TreeSet <>();
setY.add( "Jan" );
setY.add( "Marsha" );
setY.add( "Marsha" );
setY.add( "Marsha" );
setY.add( "Cindy" );
```

> setY.toString(): [Cindy, Jan, Marsha]

## `SequencedCollection`

By the way, Java 21 brought sequenced collections. See [*JEP 431: Sequenced Collections*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/431).

The more general super-interface of both `List` and `NavigableSet`/`SortedSet` is [`SequencedCollection`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/21/docs/api/java.base/java/util/SequencedCollection.html).

```
SequencedCollection < Integer > sequence = List.of( 42 , 7 , 99 ) ;
```

Comment: Well explained! For future visitors, [this link](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk7u/jdk7u6/jdk/file/8c2c5d63a17e/src/share/classes/java/util/List.java) can be useful to understand the `hashCode` and `equals` methods of `List` better.

Comment: Cleared my all doubts, Thanks @Basil Bourque.